# Speeding up Solr Indexing

Tags: lucene, solr

I am kind of working on speeding up my Solr Indexing speed. I just want to know by default how many threads(if any) does Solr use for indexing. Is there a way to increase/decrease that number.

Comment: Tried many ways, but now say I am using a csv file to post the data. Also that brings me to my next question, are there any benchmarks on performances of different methods of indexing say using DIH, xml files, csv file, json objects etc.

Answer (score 13):

When you index a document, several steps are performed :

- the document is analyzed,
- data is put in the RAM buffer,
- when the RAM buffer is full, data is flushed to a new segment on disk,
- if there are more than ${mergeFactor} segments, segments are merged.

The first two steps will be run in as many threads as you have clients sending data to Solr, so if you want Solr to run three threads for these steps, all you need is to send data to Solr from three threads.

You can configure the number of threads to use for the fourth step if you use a ConcurrentMergeScheduler (http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/ConcurrentMergeScheduler.html). However, there is no mean to configure the maximum number of threads to use from Solr configuration files, so what you need is to write a custom class which call setMaxThreadCount in the constructor.

My experience is that the main ways to improve indexing speed with Solr are :

- buying faster hardware (especially I/O),
- sending data to Solr from several threads (as many threads as cores is a good start),
- using the Javabin format,
- using faster analyzers.

Although [StreamingUpdateSolrServer](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/StreamingUpdateSolrServer.html) looks interesting for improving indexing performance, [it doesn't support the Javabin format](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1565). Since Javabin parsing is *much* faster than XML parsing, I got better performance by sending bulk updates (800 in my case, but with rather small documents) using CommonsHttpSolrServer and the Javabin format.

You can read http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveIndexingSpeed for further information.

Comment: Thanks much for the reply.                                                                     I tried your first suggestion(posting documents via multiple threads) before posting this question. I did not get any big improvement. That's why I wanted to know if there was something else that I could try. Having said that there I was posting docs(actually was streaming) using multiple threads but to a single core. I was doubting if that essentially was posting sequentially and hence had no big improvement. Also I was constructing the docs being posted from a CSV file,if that makes any difference.

Comment: XML deserialization can make the indexing process very slow. I updated my answer to add the advice to use the Javabin format.

Comment: Also, StreamingUpdateSolrServer does now support Javabin as well.

Comment: True Eric, the mentioned issue has been fixed. Thank you for the update.

Comment: in Solr 3.6 and beyond, StreamingUpdateSolrServer supports javabin.

Comment: In (at least) 4.0, you can configure the number of threads used by the ConcurrentMergeScheduler in solrconfig.xml via the  maxThreadCount parameter.  e.g.:  <mergeScheduler class="org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler"> <int name="maxThreadCount">6</int> </mergeScheduler>

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://searchhub.org/2012/03/05/scaling-solr-indexing-with-solrcloud-hadoop-and-behemoth/) describes an approach to scaling indexing with SolrCloud, Hadoop and Behemoth. This is for Solr 4.0 which hadn't been released at the time this question was originally posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the content in external storage like file;

What are all the field that contains huge size of content,in schema set ***stored="false"*** for that corresponding field and  store the content for that field in external file using some efficient file system hierarchy.

It improves **indexing  by 40 to 45% reduced time**. But when doing search, search time speed is some what increased.***For search*** ***it took 25% more time*** than normal search.